# Set value to cell if value temp cell > value source cell (Process multi cell by array)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have multi sheet have Same format (header).

- Cost_Tmp: Calculate cost from raw data by arrayformula function
- Cost: If Cost_tmp change and > Cost then I want to copy value from Cost_Tmp to Cost.
- I have multi sheet so I would use array to speed-up script process
- Column index can change -> I Would like to use column header to refer to column.
- I wrote this pice of code to do that but It doesn't work (copy function work but creteria of if function doesn't work). I don't know how to compare 2 object value of array. The problem is if function below
- if (data[i][Cost_Tmp_col] > data[i][Cost_col].toString())
- Here is exaple sheet: [Google sheet testing sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E5BEdOzULVd9K04CTCamu9BT8d6COfCF4ba62G9elLA/edit?usp=sharing)

```html
function updateCost() {
  var mysheetname = ["RETAIL_ORDER","SEA FOOD_ORDER","HAMPER_ORDER","GARDEN_ORDER"];

  for(var j = 0;j < mysheetname.length;j++)

  {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(mysheetname[j]);
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var Cost_col = headers.indexOf('Cost');
    var Cost_Tmp_col = headers.indexOf('Cost_Tmp');

    var dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mysheetname[j])
      .getDataRange();
    var CostRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mysheetname[j])
      .getRange(1,Cost_col+1,sheet.getLastRow(),1);
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    var newData = []
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var cost_tmp_val = data[i][Cost_Tmp_col];
      if (data[i][Cost_Tmp_col] > data[i][Cost_col].toString()) {
        data[i][Cost_col] = data[i][Cost_Tmp_col].toString();
      }
      newData.push(new Array(data[i][Cost_col]));
      
    }
    CostRange.setValues(newData);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your question? Can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image?

Comment: @Tanaike I really appreciate, you help me 2 times before. sorry for poor english. Another guy sloved my issuse. Again thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issues:

- You want to compare two numbers, but (at least) one of the items in the comparison is a string `data[i][Cost_col].toString()`. Do not use [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) if you want to compare numbers.
- You are only pushing values to `newData` if the condition is met, whereas you want all `Cost` column to be populated (not just the rows that have to get updated).
- The [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array) `new Array(number)` will create an empty array with the number's length. That's not what you want to accomplish.

#### Solution:

- Do not use [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) if you want to compare numbers.
- Retrieve the values corresponding to `CostRange` and modify those values instead of creating a new array via `newData`.

#### Code sample:

```
function updateCost() {
  var mysheetname = ["RETAIL_ORDER","SEA FOOD_ORDER","HAMPER_ORDER","GARDEN_ORDER"];
  for(var j = 0;j < mysheetname.length;j++)  {
    var sheetname = mysheetname[j];
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetname);
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var Cost_col = headers.indexOf('Cost') + 1;
    var Cost_Tmp_col = headers.indexOf('Cost_Tmp') + 1;
    var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
    var CostRange = sheet.getRange(1,Cost_col,sheet.getLastRow(),1);
    var costValues = CostRange.getValues();
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
      var rowData = data[i];
      var costTemp = rowData[Cost_Tmp_col - 1];
      if (costTemp > rowData[Cost_col - 1]) {
        costValues[i] = [costTemp];
      }
    }
    CostRange.setValues(costValues);
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- I modified your script a bit in order to avoid repetitive tasks (e.g. accessing `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mysheetname[j])` or `data[i]` multiple times).
- I'm assuming that triggering this when the spreadsheet is edited is not the issue, but only making the script do the appropriate actions. If you need help with that, take a look at [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite).

Comment: Your code perfecty work. I will update your code to question for someone else need it. Thank you so much